# Eclipse not showing reference IDs for strings

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, reference

I'm trying to get the reference ids for some strings. A few days ago they were visible in the variables view in the debug perspective. Today however they are not.

What I see is:

```
Name | Value    
Test | "Hello"
```

What I want to see is:

```
Name | Value
Test | "Hello" (id = 21)
```

What did I change and how do I change it back?

Answer (score 1):

- go to the Debug perspective
- select the 'Variables' tab or the 'Breakpoints' tab
- invoke the drop-down menu that proposes two submenus 'Layout >' and 'Java >'
- select 'Java Preferences' in the Java sub-menu
- select 'Java/Debug/Detail Formatters'
- click on 'In detail pane only' in the section named 'Show variable details ('toString()' value)
  You're done!
  There might be other ways to do the same, but this one works for me.